# TextView value from Row Position ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

What I have setup is a ListView that has 1 TextView and 2 Buttons. What I am trying to do is when the first button is clicked, I want it to give me the value in the TextView.

I have spent lot of time looking this up but I can't find an answer that will properly work. I have this code in my onClick button method:

```
// position of the button
int position = pendingList.getPositionForView((View) view.getParent());


//extract the text
String pendingUserText = pendingUsers.get(position).get(R.id.name);
```

Something to note is that I use a ArrayList map to populate my listview and a simple adapter. When I do this, the problem that I get is when I try to Toast.make and then I pass "pendingUserText" Through it, I get a null value. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the XML file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:height="30dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Accept"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#3366CC"
    android:textColor="#B0E0E6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp"
    android:onClick="addButtonClicked"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/declineButton"
    android:text="Decline"
    android:textColor="#B0E0E6"
    android:background="#3366CC"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
    android:clickable="true"
    />'
```

Here is my ListAdapter

```
istView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendslistView);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    FriendsActivity.this, pendingUsers,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] {TAG_FROMUSER}, new int[] { R.id.name});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Pls post the layout xml files and related code to your Listview and adapter.

Comment: Would you like to read a good tutorial and redesign your code?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid What do you mean?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid I would definitely like to take a look at it.

Comment: The problem is that `pendingUsers.get(position).get(R.id.name)` seems to return `null`. What is the class of `pendingUsers.get(position)`? `HashMap`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp answered my own quest :). Thanks for the support everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

```
RelativeLayout vwParentRow = (RelativeLayout)view.getParent();
    TextView pending =(TextView)vwParentRow.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

for anyone that needs it.